# why file contents not saving in 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a file example.txt who look like this

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

but i am unable to read and save file contents in my array.

Here is my code which i am trying for almost 1 hour

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int arr[10][5];
    int i=0,j=0;
    ifstream in("example.txt",ios::in);

    if(!in)
        {
            cout<<"File not Found";
        }
    else
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
        {
            for( j = 0;j<5;j++)
            {
                 in >> arr[i][j];
            }
        }

    }

    int x=0,y=0;
    for(x=0;x<10;x++)
    {
        for(y=0;y<5;y++)
        {
            cout<<arr[x][y];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Is anything i am doing wrong , cant find out the error!

I am getting these raw values

[image]

Comment: This is C++. Why not limit the scope of your loop variables? `for(int i = 0; ...)`

Comment: `arr[i][j]` is type `int`. so the system is reading an (possibly multi-digit) integer, not only single digit (character).

Comment: You need to put spaces between 0's in your text file.

Comment: I edit the question , and there is a space between 0's in my file @erip

Comment: So it's a `5x5` and not a `10x5`? You're either not giving us real code or not giving us a real input file.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Above code with input files 5x5 of 0 and spaces give 5 lines of 5 0 before 5 lines of 5 `-858993460` without any space (which is what I expected). Are you sure you are not reading an empty file???

Comment: yes i am sure, file is not empty

Comment: Are you executing the executable in the same directory that contains `example.txt`? If you see `a.out` and `example.txt` in the same directory and execute in that directory, it should work...

Comment: I solved it! Thankyou all , some file error